# solving quadratic inequality $ 5-x^2<8$

Tags: inequality

I can see graphically why x can be any real number, but can this be solved algebraically? I'm having a hard time with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the following steps

1. Isolate $x^2$: $$5-x^2<8 \implies 5-8<x^2 \implies -3<x^2$$
2. Now observe that since $x^2$ is always nonnegative, i.e. $$0<x^2$$ the above inequality holds trivially for all values of $x$, since $$-3<0<x^2$$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2\ge0$ for all real number, so $5-x^2\le5<8$

Comment: So 5-x^2 is always going to be <= 5 because x^2 is going to be >= 0... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Algebraically it's equivalent to find solutions of the inequality $$x^2+3>0.$$
The polynomial on the left hand side has no real roots, because the discriminant is negative. The coefficient at $x^2$ is positive; these two facts ensure us that the polynomial is always strictly positive and hence the solution of the inequality is $x\in \Bbb R$.

Comment: I forgot how to find the discriminant and what it is, but I will do a quick search on Google. Thanks!